# Spring 3.5 - requests are working by postman but not by web application

Tags: java, spring, fetch

I am running into some trouble trying to figure out why my request is working on postman but not in the app (using fetchjs). The following is my request in the postman:
[image]

and how it looks like in web application:

[image]

and here you can find my SecurityConfiguration:

```html
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't post code as images as those are totally unreadable. Post them as text with code tags for formatting.

Comment: idea: `Referer=http://localhost:3000` ( *should* (!) raise problems with `http://localhost:8080` !?;)

Comment: ... https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ ... + response headers/status would be nice for "guessing":) ;p

Answer (score 1):

I think the request is blocked by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

In other words, the remote server only allows requests from a limited set of URLs, localhost is not one of them.

**Postman works because it doesn't do this check.**

See https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/